# Find Duplicate entries when 2 criteria met and mark them

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way in VBA to find duplicate entries when criteria in 2 columns meet?

I have two columns of data. First column has got dates and the second one amounts. The problem is to find and highlight all amounts that has got a duplicate amount and the same date in corresponding column?

I have so far managed to find a code to highlight duplicates on 1 criteria.

Here is the code

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateAmounts()
      Dim cel As Variant
      Dim myrng As Range

      Set myrng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row)
      myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

      For Each cel In myrng
      clr = 10
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 Then
          cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 26
      clr = clr + 10

      End If
      Next

      MsgBox ("All duplicates found and coloured")

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not remove it via the menu Data|RemoveDuplicates?

Comment: Hi, I need to work on those duplicates so they cannot be removed . If so I would select two columns and press remove duplicates and that would be all .

Comment: Are you able to add extra columns? If so, could concatenate dates & amounts and use the COUNTIF function with conditional formatting.

Comment: I would use `sumifs`. Check for the date and the amount then sum the dates. Unless you're doing historical accounting the sum should be 0 when there are no matches and more when there are.

Comment: Use a conditional formatting rule based upon a formula that implements the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a VBA attempt at the same thing I have given formula to. I don't think it was necessary but OP might learn from it anyways. Cheers!

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
Dim LastRow As Long, DatesCol As Long, AmountsCol As Long, a As Double, b As Double
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
DatesCol = 4 'D column with dates
AmountsCol = 5 'E column with amounts
Columns(DatesCol).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'dates lose color
For i = 1 To LastRow 'for each row
    If i <> 1 Then 'had some fun with row 0 error
        a = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
                  Range(Cells(1, DatesCol), Cells(i - 1, DatesCol)), _
                  Range(Cells(1, DatesCol), Cells(i - 1, DatesCol)), _
                  Cells(i, DatesCol), _
                  Range(Cells(1, AmountsCol), Cells(i - 1, AmountsCol)), _
                  Cells(i, AmountsCol)) 'counts the date values associated with recurrences before
    Else
        a = 0 'if it's first row I declared a zero, I don't know why
    End If

    If i <> LastRow Then 'yeah, last row stuff
        b = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
                  Range(Cells(i + 1, DatesCol), Cells(LastRow, DatesCol)), _
                  Range(Cells(i + 1, DatesCol), Cells(LastRow, DatesCol)), _
                  Cells(i, DatesCol), _
                  Range(Cells(i + 1, AmountsCol), Cells(LastRow, AmountsCol)), _
                  Cells(i, AmountsCol)) 'counts the date values associated with recurrences after
    Else
        b = 0 'if it's the last row, there are definitely none after
    End If

    If a <> 0 Or b <> 0 Then Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 26 'if either one of them isn't 0 then the date value gets a nice background color
Next i
End Sub
```

With a `Countifs` and some optimisation it will look like this:

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
Dim LastRow As Long, DatesCol As Long, AmountsCol As Long
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
DatesCol = 4 'D column with dates
AmountsCol = 5 'E column with amounts
Columns(DatesCol).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'dates lose color
For i = 1 To LastRow 'for each row
If 1 < Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range(Cells(1, DatesCol), Cells(LastRow, DatesCol)), _
                  Cells(i, DatesCol), _
                  Range(Cells(1, AmountsCol), Cells(LastRow, AmountsCol)), _
                  Cells(i, AmountsCol)) _
                  Then Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 26 ' 'counts the date values associated with occurrences if there's more than one then the date gets a nice background color
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That's the masterpiece I was looking for. Macro processes all data in few sec. all the result is what I need, i.e, 2 criteria match, the same amount and the same value date corresponding to each amount. Thank you very much! Cheers

Comment: Hi @user3819867 its really working amazingly, I'm wondering how to add more criteria (3,4,5..) for the same. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: `CountIfs()` arguments come in pairs, add `[Range(Cells(1,col{n}),Cells(LastRow, col{n})), Cells(i, col{n})]` where `col{n}` is the nth column as long integer where you are looking for matches. For all practical purpuses that should be enough, I think it goes up to n=26.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS($D$1:$D1,$D$1:$D1,$D2,$E$1:$E1,$E2)+SUMIFS($D3:$D$1048576,$D3:$D$1048576,$D2,$E3:$E$1048576,$E2)
```

And for working with VBA:

```
=SUMIFS(R1C4:R[-1]C4,R1C4:R[-1]C4,RC4,R1C5:R[-1]C5,RC5)+SUMIFS(R[1]C4:R1048576C4,R[1]C4:R1048576C4,RC4,R[1]C5:R1048576C5,RC5)
```

These sum **D** (assumed to be dates) based on **D** (dates) and **E** (amounts) both before and after given row. Change the *C5* and *C4* where needed to fit your dataset.

To get to the true/false statements I'd say just put a `0<>` before:

```
=0<>SUMIFS(R1C4:R[-1]C4,R1C4:R[-1]C4,RC4,R1C5:R[-1]C5,RC5)+SUMIFS(R[1]C4:R1048576C4,R[1]C4:R1048576C4,RC4,R[1]C5:R1048576C5,RC5)
```

Comment: Plus to be real prudent I'd use `Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row` in lieu of the constant `1048576`.

Comment: Formula way is no good for me. I've tried to enter this formula by For loop in only 1000 rows and the file broke down. Not enough memory to process it. Moreover, the file has got around 15,000 rows to check so this is not applicable.

Comment: The functions needs to be there but for a split-second. You could insert then fix the value.

Comment: How do you mean "insert" and "fix value"?

Comment: `Cell.FormulaR1C1= [something]`; then
`Cell.Value2 = Cell.Value2`

Comment: Actually I was a dumbass, it could work with `=COUNTIFS($D$1:$D$65536,$D2,$E$1:$E$65536,$E2)>1` / `=COUNTIFS(R1C4:R65536C4,RC4,R1C5:R65536C5,RC5)>1` too.