# Highlighting duplicate values based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to highlight duplicate values based on 4 criteria. As shown in the below snap, i need to highlight the Emp_Name, if the **Emp ID, Group ID, Department Name** and **Emp_Name** are exists more than one in the column.

[image]

I need only macro not formula, since data might exceed more than ***100K*** i tried this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543699/find-duplicate-entries-when-2-criteria-met-and-mark-them) but unable to edit it as required and I,m so confused how to do it.

Please help me out :)

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?  There's a built-in "Highlight Duplicates" - select columns A:D, then go to Conditional Formatting, using the "Highlight Duplicates" rule.  This will highlight all rows that are duplicates.

Comment: It will find and highlight the duplicate values column wise and i need to highlight them row wise with respect to the entire column

Comment: what do you mean it highlights column wise? It should highlight the cells

Comment: Please pardon me if its not clear to you. If I'm using conditional formatting its highlighting the duplicate cells with respect to single column. However, what i need is it should check in multiple column (please check the above snap) if all the cell value in those column matches then only it should highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a macro, this should get you started.  It uses a nested for loop to compare each row to every other row.

```
Sub FormatDuplicates()

    Dim LastRow As Integer, LoopCounter As Integer, LoopCounter2 As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        If LoopCounter > 1 Then
            For LoopCounter = 2 to LastRow
                For LoopCounter2 = 2 to LastRow
                    If Not LoopCounter = LoopCounter2 Then
                        If .Range("A" & LoopCounter & ":D" & LoopCounter) = _
                        .Range("A" & LoopCounter2 & ":D" & LoopCounter2) Then

                            '    Apply formatting here to .Range("A" & LoopCounter &
                            '    ":D" & LoopCounter)

                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help DGulledge, the above macro is not working.. Im still working on it :)

Comment: I'm really sorry I have tried the above macro with formatting as you mentioned in the comment. However, nothing is getting highlighted..